# Django: How to create a separate endpoint login link for admin/staff users

Tags: python, django

Currently I've been using the generic login/register links (.../account/login, .../account/register etc) which lets all users (staff and non-staff) to login. I'm creating a separate app for only staff members and I'd like to have a separate endpoint link (.../acccount/staff-login) that would only allow staff members to get tokens. This seems pretty basic but I haven't been able to find anything for this.

Edit: MY SOLUTION : I simply reused the existing ObtainAuthToken view, and added a simple check for is_staff, if the user isn't staff I send an error status.

```
class StaffAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer

    if coreapi_schema.is_enabled():
        schema = ManualSchema(
            fields=[
                coreapi.Field(
                    name="username",
                    required=True,
                    location='form',
                    schema=coreschema.String(
                        title="Username",
                        description="Valid username for authentication",
                    ),
                ),
                coreapi.Field(
                    name="password",
                    required=True,
                    location='form',
                    schema=coreschema.String(
                        title="Password",
                        description="Valid password for authentication",
                    ),
                ),
            ],
            encoding="application/json",
        )

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {
            'request': self.request,
            'format': self.format_kwarg,
            'view': self
        }

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return self.serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        if (not user.is_staff):                 ## this is what I added
            return Response(status = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({'token': token.key})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using two different link...
1.link_for_non-staf
2.link_for_staf
Now listen that request in two different function in views.py.

```
def link_for_staff(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        staff_form=AuthenticationForm(request,data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username=staff_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            passowrd=staff_form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user=authenticate(username=username,passowrd=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
```

Similarly you can create a another function to listen non-staff login request.
In your staff link no any other can login.
Don't forgot to import all import modules and variable names may be differ according to your choice.

Comment: Thanks your code gave me the idea to use the existing obtain_auth_token view and simply add a check for is_staff before sending the token.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is create another authentication and check the user that's trying to login.

you can simply use IF statement.

```
`
if User.object.filter(fieldname=value, is_staff=True).exists():
    do the auth......
else:
    return the user back with error messeage
 `
```

This will allow only the staff on the staff app. there are many ways to do this but this is the simplest.